# Wrk load testing, Post request with payload from json file

Tags: load-testing, wrk

Does wrk support specifying a json body with a path to a file like vegeta load testing?

https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta

Also is there a way to overwrite variables in the post request body payload?

For example if I have a payload like

```
{
  "id": "{{value}}"
}
```

Is there a way to inject and overwrite `{{value}}` during wrk run time with unique and different values?